# jQuery Masonry plugin broken in IE7 - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

Visit [this link](http://floriehuppertdesign.com/scrapblog) to view the page in question.

Any ideas here?  I'm pulling my hair out.  Only a problem in IE7.  IE8 works just fine.  View the site in Chrome/Firefox to see how it should look.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything masonry related on that page.

Comment: Sorry, the maintenance mode was still up.  Please don't downvote for that.

Comment: @Cogweb +1 just coz you made me laugh :)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2347902/901048 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1188307/901048 and possibly http://forum.jquery.com/topic/stuck-with-jquery-masonry for similar problems and possible solutions.

Comment: @mblase75 I checked all of those already, honestly.  No dice :(

Answer (score 0):

My preliminary assumption would be that this is a float issue with IE7 (see: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/escape-floats.html). That browser has difficulty calculating height in a variety of circumstances. I've noticed that you have set:

```
.scrap-post-item
.scrap-post-item a
.scrap-post-item p
.scrap-post-item img
```

to all have `float: left;`

There's no reason for that to accomplish this layout as only the container of those items needs to be floated.

So that's where I'd start, get rid of the extraneous floats. If the browser isn't passing the correct height of a container to masonry, it's impossible for masonry to layout the page properly. You may also have success with the "hack" solution of adding `zoom: 1;` to one of the higher up containers that is being floated to cause IE7 and prior to calculate the layout properly.